# Spring Tutorial: Folders hidden in package explorer view in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm following the Spring consuming REST API tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

After git cloning gs-rest-service/initial project, I imported this project as an existing project in Spring Tool Suite.

However in the Package Explorer View, I don't see any folders in src/main, however in the hard drive, and when I try to create a new folder I do see these folders: `java/hello` again. How do I make these folders appear in the Package Explorer Sidebar in Eclipse?

[[image]]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSwT6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is your package empty ?

Have you refreshed your workspace ?

Check that under your 'Java Element Filters' you don't have 'empty packages' checked ?

Answer (score 0):

Package Explorer is a virtual view of your project, so what you're seeing is that virtual representation has "relocated" Java sources to a virtual folder in that view. Package Explorer represents source locations (such as `src/main/java`) as a package container instead of an ordinary folder. Look at the first node under the project; it has a different icon and is labeled `src/main/java` - that's where the source files are presented.

[image]

If you want a more literal file-system view, open the Navigator view. Also look at Project Explorer, which shows both the literal view and the "virtual" view that Package Explorer shows.